# How to get data from oracle database in hourly basis

Tags: sql, oracle

i have one table call CMH_VITALSIGN, There is one column in this table as Time, which stores date and time (3/2/2016 11:33:17 AM). Now i want to get data from this table on hourly basis. MY Table columns is ..

```
(
  VITAL_SIGNNO      NUMBER,
  CONSULT_NO        VARCHAR2(16 BYTE),
  REG_NO            VARCHAR2(16 BYTE),
  ADMISSION_NO      VARCHAR2(16 BYTE),
  DN_NO             VARCHAR2(16 BYTE),
  CONSULT_DT        DATE,
  TEMP_C            NUMBER(4,2),
  TEMP_F            NUMBER(5,2),
  PULSE             NUMBER(3),
  RR                NUMBER(2),
  BP_HIGHER         NUMBER(5,2),
  BP_LOWER          NUMBER(5,2),
  RESP              NUMBER(3),
  SPECIALITY_NO     VARCHAR2(16 BYTE),
  ENTERED_BY        VARCHAR2(16 BYTE),
  ENTRY_TIMESTAMP   DATE,
  UPDATED_BY        VARCHAR2(16 BYTE),
  UPDATE_TIMESTAMP  DATE,
  COMPANY_NO        VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)           DEFAULT 1,
  SL_NO             VARCHAR2(16 BYTE)
)
```

now i want to show data as line chart hourly base...

```
SELECT to_date(ENTRY_TIMESTAMP) DAY,
  DECODE(TO_CHAR(ENTRY_TIMESTAMP,'HH24'),'11',pulse, 0) "00",
  DECODE(TO_CHAR(ENTRY_TIMESTAMP,'HH24'),'12',pulse,0)"01",
  DECODE(TO_CHAR(ENTRY_TIMESTAMP,'HH24'),'13',pulse,0) "02",
  DECODE(TO_CHAR(ENTRY_TIMESTAMP,'HH24'),'14',pulse,0) "03"
FROM CMH_VITALSIGN
WHERE pulse IS NOT NULL 
--where to_date(ENTRY_TIMESTAMP) ='01_MAY-2010' 
--GROUP by to_char(ENTRY_TIMESTAMP,'YYYY-MON-DD'), to_date(ENTRY_TIMESTAMP) 
ORDER BY to_date(ENTRY_TIMESTAMP);
```

Can anybody help me in this query.

Comment: Oracle or mySQL or both? can you please remove the wrong tag, if any? Besides, can you post an exampe of your data and desired result?

Comment: And can you pls also post what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR ( ENTRY_TIMESTAMP, 'HH24') AS hour_num,
       PULSE,
       TEMP_C,
       TEMP_F,
       RR,
       BP_HIGHER,
       BP_LOWER,
       RESP
  FROM cmh_vitalsign
WHERE TRUNC (ENTRY_TIMESTAMP) = TO_DATE ( '3/2/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
and  ADMISSION_NO = 'A011009011297';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want calculate data per every hour try implement this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( d, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24') hour, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT SYSDATE + LEVEL / 26 / 60 d
      FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL < 1000)
GROUP BY TO_CHAR( d, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24')
```